# Sql server Code Reuse

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with about 30 fields.  I current have several stored procedures which access either a (aggregated)  view of this table or the table itself.  For many of these SPs I would like to assure that the returned records have all the same fields with the same column names.  Is there a way to do this where I don't have to change 20 stored procs if I do need to change the output.

My way around it thus far is to provide clients with lists of ID which they then call SP's that return the data however this seems to be slow compared with getting the data in one shot.  I have also considered using the formatting stored procs with a cursor from inside the search stored procs but was unsure if that would really buy me a whole lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical way to define a standardised and consistent data access method across multiple stored procedures in SQL Server to use Views.

Now your problem description seems to suggest that you are already using Views in order to manage your data access. If you are indeed unable to use Views for a specific reason, perhaps you can clarify the nature of your problem further for us.